# How to retrive and use data from "window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan" PhoneGap Zxing plugin?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am using PhoneGap to develop an Android App. I am using ZXing plugin in order to scan a QR-Code.

In index.html, I put a button in order to scan a QR-Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="scanCode();">
```

Here is the code of scanCode in the java-script file:

```
var scanCode = function() {
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
    alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
            + ". Format: " + result.format
            + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);    
}, function(error) {
    alert("Scan failed: " + error);
});
```

}

I want to retrieve datas from "result", especially "result.text" in order to use them in another html file.

How can I please do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`result.text` is already the scanned text.

Try this:

```
var thetext = result.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner talks about adding src.com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner.java.